# Xcode shows ‘there was an internal api error’ when installing Kodi to iPhone

Tags: xcode, kodi

I tried downloading kodi to my iPhone6 through Xcode and iOS app singer
I followed everything step by step as shown in this link
https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-install-kodi-on-iphone-or-ipad-without-jailbreaking-3634908/%3famp
But when I tried installing it to my iPhone which was the last step, it shows an internal api error

I searched every forum for help and tried fixing it but it is clearly not working

Please help

Comment: there are very low chance of success. Apple didn't allow to publish kodi even on appstore. by a similar experience I suggest you to not try to install kodi unless you got jailbreak device

Comment: What is the alternate to Kodi??

Comment: in this case you should seek for alternative to iphone

Comment: Maybe I will, Thanks 4 replying

Comment: and if you still work on that and find any solution feel free to mention it as your own answer to your question if you find working solution.